Will jvm release memory?
I am a Java developer, using jdk 1.8. My application runs in k8s. The memory limit of each pod is 2.5g. When my application runs for a period of time, a full gc occurs, but the memory will not be released.
My jvm configuration is as follows
 -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -Xmn256m -XX:PermSize=128m -Xss256k  -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=128m -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
When my application runs for a period of time, the heap memory will reach 2048m. After performing gc, the memory occupied by the entire pod will not decrease. This will cause some bad situations. The memory of the entire pod will exceed the 2.5g limit. K8s The pod will be restarted, which will cause the application to be temporarily unavailable.
Is it because my xms and xmx are configured to have the same size, causing the memory not to be reclaimed after gc?

AFAIK, if you set -Xms and -Xmx the same, memory will never be released, and otherwise it depends on the specific garbage collector you specified and its settings. And, again AFAIK, the concurrent mark and sweep collector you specified does not release memory back to the OS. In more recent Java versions, some of the GCs will release memory back by default, or explicitly configured to do so.

What you want is called memory uncommit or heap uncommit.
The easiest way would be to use the Shenandoah garbage collector, you can do so by providing the -XX:+UseShenandoahGC flag.

Heap uncommit. Many GCs already do heap uncommits when they think it is a good idea: Shenandoah does it asynchronously even without the GC requests, G1 sure does it on explicit GC requests, pretty sure Serial and Parallel also do it in some conditions.

Blog post source for that quote https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/21-heap-uncommit/
Here is more information on shenandoah from the openjdk website (search "uncommit") https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/shenandoah/Main

Calling System.gc() is a bad practice and there is no guarantee it will actually do anything.
